# TensorFlow: Import image into tensor-flow model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am new on deep learning. To practicing I trained a simple Handwriting model with tensor-flow and mnist. After loading mnist I made model and trained that:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')/255
x_test =  x_test.astype('float32')/255
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(100,activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100,activation = 'sigmoid'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10,activation = 'sigmoid'),
])
```

As you can see, I flatted my first layer into 784 px One-dimensional array.

Now on paper I wrote a number :

[image]

After changing it's scale into 28*28 with image editor(GIMP),I loaded my image into my cods:

```
img_width, img_height = 28, 28
img = image.load_img('rgb_seven.jpeg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
```

This is x result:

```
array([[[167., 170., 179.],
        [168., 171., 180.],
        [168., 171., 180.],
        ...,
        [174., 175., 180.],
        [174., 175., 180.],
        [167., 170., 175.]],

       [[173., 176., 185.],
        [172., 175., 184.],
        [166., 169., 178.],
```

and :

```
images = np.vstack(x)
images
```

And it's images result is :

```
array([[167., 170., 179.],
       [168., 171., 180.],
       [168., 171., 180.],
       ...,
       [166., 173., 179.],
       [166., 173., 179.],
       [166., 173., 179.]], dtype=float32)
```

Before to predict I have to do flat my images so I do this:

```
x_images_flattened = images.reshape(len(images),28*28)
```

But I got error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-db6c299f19c6> in <module>
      3 images = np.vstack(x)
      4 # images
----> 5 x_images_flattened = images.reshape(len(images),28*28)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (784,784)
```

Why I got `cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (784,784)` my image has 28*28 size.

And how can I predict that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix my problem.

```
img_width, img_height = 28, 28
img = image.load_img('two.jpeg', color_mode='grayscale',target_size=(img_width, img_height))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
plt.imshow(img_tensor,cmap=plt.cm.binary)
img_tensor = keras.utils.normalize(img_tensor,axis=1)
prediction = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0))
```

And the problem gone.